# Javascript: required suggestion in using single variable in multiple callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have node.js express application in which I need to call external URLs and save their responses in array. Hence I created two arrays one to store URLs and other to store response.

```
var urls = ['http://example.com','http://example.org','http://example.net'];
var allResponses = [];
```

I use for each loop to call urls in one go without waiting for response (asynchronous)

```
urls.forEach(url, index, urls) {
  callUrl(url, handleResponse);
}
```

Where `handleResponse` is callback function called after getting successful response

```
handleResponse function(response){
  allResponses.push(response);
}
```

As all callbacks might get called at a time which may lead to multiple access of `allResponses` at a time. Will node.js handle this condition by populating `allResponses` for all the responses fetched after hitting URLs?

Another approach is to synchronise calls by calling recursively

```
function loadResponse(index) {
    // serialize recursively
    callUrl(urls[index++], function (response) {
        allResponses.push(response);
        if (index < urls.length) {
            loadResponse(index);  // recursive call
        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know which one is the better approach?

Comment: order of response do not matter, but the array should have all the responses. The race condition should not cause over writing old response or deadlock.

Comment: it wont. Js is single threaded. And push *appends* so its impossible to override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code is the fastest ( all at the same time), but the first request may be slower than the second one, so the pushes are not in the correct order. Your second code enshures but is slow, as one request it started after the other. But which to use? Well, option three using Promise.all combines both advantages:

At first create an array of requests fullfilled somewhen:

```
var urls = ['http://example.com','http://example.org','http://example.net'];

var promises=urls.map(function(url){
 return new Promise(function(resolve){
  callUrl(url,function(resp){
    resolve(resp);
  });
 });
});
```

(Note: thats much more beautiful with bluebirds promisify...)

Now you can wait for all of them to be fullfilled:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
 console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could push all responses to the array but it wont map those responses to urls i.e urls=[url1,url2,url3] responses = [url1_Res,url2_Res,url3_Res] as all the requests would asynchronous. The following code will work if you want to push the responses in the same order as you requested urls in the arrays.

```
var req = require('request');
var urls = ['http://swapi.co/api/people/1','http://swapi.co/api/people/2','http://swapi.co/api/people/3'];
var res = [];
var receivedRes =0;
urls.forEach(function(val,index){
  console.log(`----------------Requesting url ${val}`);
  console.log(index);
  req(val,function(err,response,body){
    receivedRes++;
    // console.log(`response of the request ${body}`)
    res[index]=body;
    if(receivedRes==urls.length){
      printRes();
    }
  })
});

printRes=function(){
  res.forEach(function(val,index){
    console.log(`${index}:${val}`);
  })
}
```